# How can Laravel / Eloquent's hasMany relationship have a local key?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

In laravel, when a single entry in table A (e.g. Users) is associated with many entries in table B (e.g. Payment Methods), we define a ["has many" relationship.](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#one-to-many)

So, in User.php model we set:

```
return $this->hasMany('PaymentMethods', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

The foreign key makes sense, e.g. it could be `userid`, because each entry in the payment methods table B will have only 1 user. However, why can a local key be set here? How can the users table ever have a "payment method" id key when it is associated with many payment methods, and therefore cannot be set to a single payment method id?

Similarly, to complete the relationship, I have to define a belongsTo in the PaymentMethod.php model:

```
 return $this->belongsTo('User');
```

In here, should one only set the second parameter, i.e. the local key (e.g. to `userid`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define `local_key` if the relationship is based on a different column than the primary key of User.

If you stick with the default, primary keys are named `id` and referring columns for example `user_id`. Then you can simply do:

```
return $this->hasMany('PaymentMethod');
```

and

```
return $this->belongsTo('User');
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. In a one to many relationship, how can the user id matter for the payment methods table?

Comment: @Tom In order to establish the relationship, it takes the value of `user_id` from `PaymentMethod` to look up `User` on column `id`. If for any reason the primary key of `User` is not named `id` but anything else, you would set this as the `local_key` in the relationship.